# During Angular 5 to Angular 7 upgrade I am getting an error

Tags: angular5, upgrade, angular7

During update I am getting the below error. But this error vanishes when I compile with aot method.

Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule

Getting error while executing the below line in main.ts

bootstrap();

Comment: is it work fine if you compile without aot ?. could u post error log

Comment: it's working fine with aot compilation

Answer (score 0):

After more surfing I added the following line which solved the issue. Not sure what magic it did.

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```